# maven copy test resources into jar fails

Tags: java, maven

I need some resources that are under:

src/main/resources/__files/

Now when creating my jar with maven those are not included.

This is my pomfile:

http://pastebin.com/xMtJDei2

when creating my app I get this:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building wiremock 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ wiremock ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) @ wiremock ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/betauser/Documents/Development/wiremock/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ wiremock ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/betauser/Documents/Development/wiremock/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ wiremock ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ wiremock ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.2:jar (default-jar) @ wiremock ---
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/betauser/Documents/Development/wiremock/target/WiremockServer.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.9:copy-dependencies (copy-dependencies) @ wiremock ---
[INFO] Copying slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar to /Users/betauser/Documents/Development/wiremock/target/dependency-jars/slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar
[INFO] Copying wiremock-1.52-standalone.jar to /Users/betauser/Documents/Development/wiremock/target/dependency-jars/wiremock-1.52-standalone.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.229 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-12-11T14:40:16+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

and when I run my program and I ask the file I get:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/betauser/Documents/Development/wiremock/target/src/main/resources/__files/test-long.mp3 (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: I think `src/test/resources` should be included to `resources` instead of `testResources` to be available in normal version (though that implies the question why are those not in `src/main/resources`).

Comment: I changed the code so the resources are under src/main/resources but still doesn't work. I updated my question with the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder about the output ".../target/src/main/resources/..." .

The directory structure "src/main/resources" can't exist below "target", if your artifact builds properly.

The files you create in /src/main/resources and below belong to the classpath of your application.

Open your artifact (jar) which was created during the build process. There you should find a directory entry named "__files".